# Handle InvalidItemStateException in jackrabbit

Tags: java, multithreading, jackrabbit, jcr, multi-user

We are now experiencing a number of InvalidItemStateException in our web application caused by 2 or more users updating the same content. As far as I understood it is in design of JackRabbit to throw `javax.jcr.InvalidItemStateException` in such situation and that's ok, but I wanted to ask about the common way to handle that. We are fairly ok that the last processed change wins the update. So far we have come up with the following code:

```
repeat = false;
do {
  try {

     // Do node update/remove

  } catch (InvalidItemStateException e) {
    repeat = true;
  }
} while (repeat);
```

Is this a common pattern how to handle that? Or is it a better way to avoid such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCR (and Jackrabbit) has a node locking mechanism that may be better suited for this... sorry, though I have not used it yet to be sure that it would solve your problem.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid InvalidItemStateException every thread/user should have it's own Session object.

Comment: -1 read the java doc for the exception "...made through another Session"